# gvim options / Settings window cannot write buftype is set e382

Tags: vim, gvim, vimrc

I was trying to customize gvim a bit. I see under the `Edit` menu is an option to change `Settings Window`. It opens up but then I get the following error.

> E382 cannot write, 'buftype' option is set.

How do I write the options I change? Online I see people saying I need to add options to the vimrc file either in `~/.vimrc` or `/etc/vimrc` or `/etc/gvimrc`. I thought that I would be able to do it directly through the gvim editor, not by adding options to my `~/.vimrc` file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A serious case of RTFM, on my account. The top few lines explain how to edit it.

```
" Each "set" line shows the current value of an option (on the left).
" Hit <CR> on a "set" line to execute it.
"            A boolean option will be toggled.
"            For other options you can edit the value.
" Hit <CR> on a help line to open a help window on this option.
" Hit <CR> on an index line to jump there.
" Hit <Space> on a "set" line to refresh it.
```

I then pressed <kbd>Enter</kbd>, and my setting took affect immediately

```
on line 155
lines   number of lines in the display
    set lines=50
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to save my setting (guifont) in gvim option window, but with no success. On the next launch, it always reverted to its previous state.

Then, I wrote the same line in `~/.vimrc`, and it had the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

if you opened a remote directory and selected a file to edit you need create the tmp file in you local and set this command `set by=a write` and finally save your changes `w`.